# Approximate Expectation of $x^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am estimating the $E[x^2]$.

The function I am looking at gives you a constant value of A from 0 to 4, it is 0 from 4 to 6, and A from 6 to 10. I got that $E[x]$ to be 5. I calculated the value of A to be 1/8 ( using normalization of a wave function).

How would I go about estimating the $E[x^2]$. I am not allowed to use integrals.

What I have tried so far is treating the distribution as a discrete rather than a continous one. I did $\Delta x = x - E[x]$ and then did $\sigma ^2 = E(\Delta x ^2)$. Is this an ok way to approximate.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't at all follow.  Are you saying that you have a random variable, called $x$, which takes the value $A$ on $[0,4]\cup[6,10]$ and $0$ on $(4,6)$?  In that case, $\mathbb{E}[X]=8A$.  Or is there another "function" someplace that you've left out?

Comment: What do you mean by $E[x^2]$? The function $x\mapsto x^2$ gets very large as $x\to\infty$, so a weighted average of its values should be infinite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty unclear to the readers, but you are trying to describe a density function that is piecewise constant. It takes value $A$ on $[0,4]$ and $[6,10]$ and is $0$ elsewhere. This leads you to conclude correctly that $A=1/8$.

You can make the approximation with a number $n$ of point masses and let $n\rightarrow\infty$ to get the answer you are after.

I think you can also make a mixing distribution argument for this with a 50/50 mix of two uniform distributions, can't you?

And can't you use the fact that $\text{E}[X^2]=\text{Var}[X]+\text{E}[X]^2$? These are already known for uniform distributions, right?